# Display name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

The name '' does not exist in the current context

crn
courseid
timedays
Roomnumber

At the display, none of the items are recognized. Why is the display not seeing them when they were declared as set and gets?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


   public class Section
{

       private int crn;
       private String courseId;
       private String timeDays;
       private String roomNumber;
       private int instructor;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of a section
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="crn"></param>
    /// <param name="courseId"></param>
    /// <param name="timeDays"></param>
    /// <param name="roomNumber"></param>
    /// <param name="instructor"></param>
    public Section(int crn, string courseId, string timeDays, string roomNumber, int instructor)
        :this(crn, courseId, timeDays, roomNumber, instructor, "")
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of a section
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="crn"></param>
    /// <param name="courseId"></param>
    /// <param name="timeDays"></param>
    /// <param name="roomNumber"></param>
    /// <param name="instructor"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    public Section(int crn, string courseId, string timeDays, string roomNumber, int instructor, string message)
    {
        this.Crn = crn;
        this.CourseId = courseId;
        this.TimeDays = timeDays;
        this.RoomNumber = roomNumber;
        this.Instructor = instructor;
        this.Message = message;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the crn
    /// </summary>
    public int Crn { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// gets or sets the course id
    /// </summary>
    public string CourseId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// gets or sets the time days
    /// </summary>
    public string TimeDays { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// gets or sets the room number
    /// </summary>
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the instructor
    /// </summary>
    public int Instructor { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the message
    /// </summary>
    public string Message { get; set; }




    public void display(){
        System.Console.WriteLine("CRN =  "+ getCrn());
        System.Console.WriteLine("CourseID =   "+ getCourseId());
        System.Console.WriteLine("Time Days =  " + getTimeDays());
        System.Console.WriteLine("Room Number =  " + getRoomNumber());

    }



    }
```

Comment: You don't have to prefix the property with `get` and don't use parenthesis they're properties not methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think display() needs to look like below.  I don't know how your display() function is even compiling.

```
public void display()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("CRN =  "+ Crn);
    System.Console.WriteLine("CourseID =   "+ CourseId);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Time Days =  " + TimeDays);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Room Number =  " + RoomNmber);

}
```

In addition, since you have all your properties declared with { get; set; }, you don't need any backing member variables (the compiler automatically takes care of these for you).  So you can delete the lines that look like this:

```
private int crn;
private String courseId;
private String timeDays;
private String roomNumber;
private int instructor;
```